# Why is this hashmap search slower than expected?

Tags: rust

What is the best way to check a hash map for a key?
Currently I am using this:

```rust
let hashmap = HashMap::<&str, &str>::new();  // Empty hashmap

let name = "random";

for i in 0..5000000 {
    if !hashmap.contains_key(&name) { 
        // Do nothing
        }
}
```

This seems to be fast in most cases and takes 0.06 seconds when run as shown, but when I use it in this following loop it becomes very slow and takes almost 1 min on my machine. (This is compiling with `cargo run --release`).
The code aims to open an external program, and loop over the output from that program.

```rust
let a = vec!["view", "-h"]; // Arguments to open process with
let mut child = Command::new("samtools").args(&a)
                                        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
                                        .spawn()
                                        .unwrap();

let collect_pairs = HashMap::<&str, &str>::new();

if let Some(ref mut stdout) = child.stdout {
    for line in BufReader::new(stdout).lines() {
        // Do stuff here          
        let name = "random";
        if !collect_pairs.contains_key(&name) {
            // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason adding the `if !collect_pairs.contains_key(` line increases the run time by almost a minute. The output from child is around 5 million lines. All this code exists in `fn main()`

**EDIT**

This appears to fix the problem, resulting in a fast run time, but I do not know why the `!hashmap.contains_key` does not work well here:

```rust
let n: Option<&&str> = collect_pairs.get(name);
if match n {Some(v) => 1, None => 0} == 1 {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: This takes 152 milliseconds on my machine. Are you compiling with optimizations?

Comment: Thanks, I've just realised something strange is going on, ill try re-phrease the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to consider is that `HashMap<K, V>` uses a cryptographically secure hashing algorithm by default, so it will always be a bit slow by nature.

`get()` boils down to

```
self.search(k).map(|bucket| bucket.into_refs().1)
```

`contains_key` is

```
self.search(k).is_some()
```

As such, that `get()` is faster for you seems strange to me, it's doing more work!

Also,

```
if match n {Some(v) => 1, None => 0} == 1 {
```

This can be written more idiomatically as

```
if let Some(v) = n {
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to change the hashing algorithm to get any more speed?

Comment: @kezzos: Ultimately, there should be, however all the stuff about `Hasher` is still unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Ive found my problem, Im sorry I didnt pick up until now. I wasnt checking the return of `if !collect_pairs.contains_key(&name)` properly. It returns `true` for some reason resulting in the rest of the if block being run. I assumed it was evaluating to `false`. Thanks for the help